# Why can't I write to the encfs folder as its owner?

Tags: linux, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, s3fs

I'd like to mount s3fs to an AWS S3 bucket, encrypt the contents in the S3 bucket using encfs and write to the bucket (eg copy a file to the bucket) as ec2-user (ie. not using sudo). I cannot copy a file as the ec2-user and I have to use sudo but this is not desirable. Can anyone please advise what needs to be done so that I can get away without using sudo?

The following commands have been issued:

```
# Create mount points
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/encfs

$ sudo mkdir /mnt/s3fs

# Mount s3fs
$ sudo s3fs mybucket /mnt/s3fs -o use_cache=/tmp,allow_other

# Mount encfs. Option 'p' is used (for pre-configured paranoia mode)
$ sudo encfs /mnt/s3fs /mnt/encfs/

$ sudo chown ec2-user:ec2-user /mnt/encfs

# Create a link from ec2-user home directory
$ ln -s /mnt/encfs encrypted_folder
```

The current situation:

```
$ sudo cp plaintext.dat encrypted_folder      <- this works
$ cp plaintext.dat encrypted_folder           <- this does NOT work

cp: accessing 'encrypted_folder': Permission denied
```

Can anyone please point what I have done wrong here? and what I need to do to make it work so that I have to use sudo? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Just providing an update. To resolve the permission problem when mounting encfs include the switch --public. That should solve it.